# Vuforia detection not functionnal

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia, hololens

6.2 (64bit),
I have problem with the detection of image with Vuforia.
I create my DB, image ...
I check all of this:

1. Check "Asset > Editor > QCAR > ImageTargetTextures > YourDB"
2. If your image imagename_scaled.jpg doesn't true (black/white/transparant) delete it.
3. Drag your Image Texture to  "Asset > Editor > QCAR > ImageTargetTextures > YourDB"
4. Check Image Target in Hierarchy and then ImageTargetBehaviour in Inspector, Choose again your database.
5. Save scene

But it's not functionnal, when i put the application on my hololens, i can't detect the image .... 
And I can't see my image on my imagetarget.
Do you have any ideas or advice?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Have you activated the database on the AR Camera?

Comment: Of course, put i can't active my camera in the settings of vuforia and I don't know why .. I will tell if if I found why ! Thanks for your answer Dracos18s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try out the vuforia example and it worked?
Only your own images now don't work?

Maybe your images dont have a 4-5star rating in the database.
When I worked with the vuforia database I didnt realize that the star rating in the database means how good the images are recognized.

Another thing is that the images are recognized only when you are close enough. You must close in to about 10x the size of the image. The vuforia A4 example pictures can be recognized at a distance of around 2m, when your pictures are smaller you must be closer for the system to work.

There was another thing I had to do after importing the database into unity.
I went to Editor->Vuforia->ImageTargetTexture->MyDatabase. There I changed the Texture Shape of every single image from Cube to 2D. Aftwards my images could be seen in the editor.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes Image has 5 stars. But I found the problem, If you use Unity 2017 you must have the last version of Vuforia, and there are some new parameters :)